# If spring-cloud-stream is on classpath, spring-boot auto-configuration is looking for a default binder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am working on a spring-boot multi-module application where we are creating a single custom fatty jar to bind all the third parties dependencies. The `Spring cloud stream` is also part of this fatty jar. Our application was running on `spring-cloud-stream` version `2.1.3.RELEASE` (`spring-boot 2.1.6.RELEASE` ) and we are upgrading it to `3.0.2.RELEASE` (`spring-boot 2.2.4.RELEASE` ).
We are experiencing here an issue. If a particular module where there is no use of the `spring-cloud-stream`, but the `spring-cloud-stream` is on classpath so the spring-boot `auto-configuration` is looking for a `default binder`.

```
{"mdc":{},"timestamp":"2020-03-20 12:53:04.150","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
"message":"Application run failed", "exception":"\r\norg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <b>A default binder has been requested, but there is no binder available</b>\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal
 (DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport
 (SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:53)\r\n\
 org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance
 (SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:46)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)\r\n\
 org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.s
ements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.s
ements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)\r\n\
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)\r\n\
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)\r\n\
 org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)\r\n\
 org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)\r\n\
 org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)\r\n\
 org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)\r\n\
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)\r\n\
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)\r\n\
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)\r\n\
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)\r\n\
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)\r\n\
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)\r\nCaused by: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A default binder has been requested, but there is no binder 
 available\r\n\
 org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:549)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:144)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:134)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:362)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:257)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58)\r\n\
 java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(Unknown Source)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)\r\n\
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)\r\n\
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)\r\n\t... 59 common frames omitted\r\n\r\n"}
```

There are two approaches we can use:-

- There is no use of `spring-cloud-stream` so either I can exclude
  `spring-cloud-stream` from that fatty jar so it will not look for any binder.
- Below dependency provides a test-binder so without having the
  implementation of real binder we can test our application by using
  it.

> ```
> <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
>        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
>        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
>        <scope>test</scope>
>    </dependency>
> ```

I would like to know if there is any other method or configurable property that I can use in the application so that I can stop looking for the default binder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going against spring-boot principles with this approach and consequently creating very large e JARs that carry dependences that are never used.
Sure you can use `exclude` attribute of `@SpringBootApplication` and exclude certain auto-configuration classes. But I am actually asking why have something on the classpath that is never use, regardless if such something is auto-config JAR or just library JAR? 
Further more, there are transient dependencies, so with s-c-stream you are bringing many other JARs that may in fact create a conflict with things you intend to use.